# Paperclip, phusion passenger - displaying images error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, passenger

I am using paperclip to upload and display images in my rails application.

Everything seems to work fine until i used phusion passenger to deploy my application on apache.

In my view.html.erb, i am using the code below to display my images:

```
 <% for image in @submission.images %>
  <p>
   <%= image_tag(image.data(:thumb)) %>
  </p>
 <% end %>
```

Code for image.rb:

```
  has_attached_file :data, :path => "/export/data/rails/images/:sub_id/:style/:basename.:extension",
                           :url => "/export/data/rails/images/:sub_id/:style/:basename.:extension",
```

apache httpd.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

ServberName duck:80
DocumentRoot /opt/html
RailsEnv test
RailsBaseUri /submission

<Directory "/opt/html/submission/">
Options -Multiviews
AllowOverride all
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

When i upload images, the images are stored in the correct place, i.e, '/export/data/rails/images/'.

However, in my view,html.erb, the images are not displayed. When i do view source for the html page, i notice that in the img src tag, submission is appended before the correct path of the image--

```
  <img alt="sub1" src="/submission/export/data/rails/images/14421/thumb/sub1.jpg">
```

I would be grateful if somneone could help me figure out what is wrong in the code above or whether i am missing something.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
<%= image_tag(image.data.url(:thumb)) %>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but it does not seem to work..error is still there

Comment: What does `Image.last.data.url` print out in your rails console? Also, a bit unrelated, do you have the :thumb style defined?

Comment: Yes i have the thumb style defined. I believe the error lies with the image src. the correct path should have been: src="/export/data/rails/images/14421/thumb/sub1.jpg". Instead it is appending submission to it such that it becomes: src="/submission/export/data/rails/images/14421/thumb/sub1.jpg"

Comment: Running 'Image.last.data.url' form the console is giving me :NoMethodError: undefined method 'has_attached_file'

Comment: Are you on rails3? You may need to `require 'paperclip'` in your console if not.

Comment: i run the Image.last.data.url command with require 'paperclip' and it is giving me the correct path: "/export/data/rails/images/14420/original/cat2.jpg?1310740778"

Comment: Is it something to do with my phusion passenger config??

Comment: If the url is correct then it is definitely the phusion passenger config. I've not dealt with phusion/passenger before so I can't help you there unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the suggestions provided :)